QGIS LAS files layer styling
I have no experience with LAS files and I am learning on the go.
I have a LAS file from a city landscape, and I need to display the points only at exact altitudes for buildings (10, 18, 24 and 30 meters). How do I do it? I tried to use the filter:
Classification = 6 AND (Z = 10 AND Z = 18 AND Z = 24 AND Z = 30)

but nothing happened! Where should I look, and what should I press on?
My goal is to make a pretty picture and that is all.

The logic of your filter is wrong, the Z Values should be combined with OR:
Classification = 6 AND (Z = 10 OR Z = 18 OR Z = 24 OR Z = 30) 

